# How to loop over XML elements in a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

The MySQL documentation has this example:

```
mysql> DELIMITER |

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE myproc ()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    ->   DECLARE xml VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '<a>X</a><a>Y</a><a>Z</a>';
    ->
    ->   WHILE i < 4 DO
    ->     SELECT xml, i, ExtractValue(xml, '//a[$i]');
    ->     SET i = i+1;
    ->   END WHILE;
    -> END |
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without hard-coding the number of elements (the value `4` in this example)?

**UPDATE**
I'm looking for a general solution. Don't be distracted by the specific XML shown in the question, it's just an example straight out of the MySQL manual page.

Comment: Mysql regex http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html?

Comment: @Shaharyar: Are you serious? Parsing XML with a _regex_?

Comment: I know its a terrible idea but seeing the `xml` posted in the question it seems the simplest solution.

Comment: the xml in the question is just a dumb example. Regex not a good general solution

Comment: Just find out the number of elements using another XPath query (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DaveB for mentioning the `count()` function, I'm now able to write this:

```
mysql> DELIMITER |

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE myproc ()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    ->   DECLARE xml VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '<a>X</a><a>Y</a><a>Z</a>';
    ->   SELECT @count := ExtractValue(@xml, 'count(//a)');
    ->
    ->   WHILE i < @count + 1 DO
    ->     SELECT xml, i, ExtractValue(xml, '//a[$i]');
    ->     SET i = i+1;
    ->   END WHILE;
    -> END |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple XML structure then you can extract the details in a single query using a recursive CTE. The following has only been tested on MySQL 8 so I can't guarantee if it works on earlier versions.

```
SET @xml =
'<objects>
    <object>
        <objectid>101</objectid>
        <objecttype>T1</objecttype>
    </object>
    <object>
        <objectid>102</objectid>
        <objecttype>T2</objecttype>
    </object>
    <object>
        <objectid>103</objectid>
        <objecttype>T3</objecttype>
    </object>
</objects>';

WITH RECURSIVE RowGenerator (SeqNum)
AS (
    SELECT 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT SeqNum + 1
    FROM RowGenerator
    WHERE SeqNum < ExtractValue(@xml, 'count(/objects/object)')
)
SELECT @RowNum := SeqNum 
, ExtractValue(@xml, '/objects/object[$@RowNum]/objectid')
, ExtractValue(@xml, '/objects/object[$@RowNum]/objecttype')
FROM RowGenerator;
```

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to the existence of `count()` in XML context... this is really all I needed! See newly posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't.**

SQL does not have XML parsing functionality.

Pass the data as a string to an environment with XML parsing functionality.

If you are trying to filter your query based on the XML data, then the answer is that you should not have stored XML in your database in the first place and are now in a lot of trouble (look up *normalisation*).

Comment: while I agree wholeheartedly, that still doesn't answer the question

Comment: @AlexR: Yes it does. "Don't" is a politer way of saying "Can't, without _extreme_ hacks that I am not going to find for you and that would be a poor answer ... even if they exist, which to be honest I seriously doubt". I think that's the closest answer you'll get to what you're looking for.

Comment: He isn't asking if he should loop over a XML elements with MySQL, he's only asking about how to do a thing that MySQL is totally capable of doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to batch process large XML files with rich, non-relational structures, then I'd say that the only challenge you're facing in processing it in MySQL is handling 1–N relationships.

Obviously, I find the example of processing 2D row-fields structured XML completely irrelevant as equally as efficiently you should be able to process raw CSV files (and any first-grader can write an XSL stylesheet to do the conversion). Instead, I'm interested in XML such as this one:

```
<batch>
  <tx id="12483" timestamp="2016-04-23 14:40:42" 
      uuid="5395db0c-0984-11e6-b4b6-e0f427e40467">
    <shop id="78" location="238 Park Ave, NYC"/>
    <items>
      <book isbn="9780062409867" 
            title="Go Set a Watchman" 
            author="Lee, Harper"
            unitprice="11.52"
            quantity="1"/>
      <book isbn="9781593080259" 
            title="The Picture of Dorian Gray" 
            author="Wilde, Oscar"
            unitprice="7.99"
            quantity="1"/>
      <book isbn="9780143039020" 
            title="The Quiet American" 
            author="Greene, Graham"
            unitprice="5.56"
            quantity="1"/>
      <book isbn="9780307277770" 
            title="The Painted Veil" 
            author="Maugham, W. Somerset"
            unitprice="7.05"
            quantity="1"/>
      <bluray asin="B017S3OP34" 
            title="The Martian" 
            year="2015"
            discs="1"
            language="English"
            unitprice="17.93"
            quantity="1"/>
    </items>
  </tx>
</batch>
```

with eg. heterogeneous collections (book and bluray), all of which may be mapped into the relational database according to a specific business logic.

Now back to your question. The number of rows of any 1–N relationship within your XML can be retrieved using XPath, ie. `extractValue('..', 'count(path/to/element)')` and then iterate over this by constructing index-specific XPath queries (alas, very imperative). For instance, you could process the above in a stored procedure such as

```
delimiter ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `import_xml`;;
CREATE PROCEDURE import_xml(xml_input MEDIUMTEXT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE k INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE row_count INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE xpath TEXT;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `books`;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE books (tx_id BIGINT, isbn BIGINT, title VARCHAR(255), author VARCHAR(63), unit_price DECIMAL(6,2), quantity TINYINT(4));

  -- process books
  -- book count in the collection
  SET row_count := extractValue(xml_input,'count(//items/book)');

  -- iterate over books
  WHILE k < row_count DO        
    SET k := k + 1;
    SET xpath := concat('//items/book[', k, ']');

    INSERT INTO books VALUES (
      extractValue(xml_input, '//tx/@id'),
      extractValue(xml_input, concat(xpath,'/@isbn')),
      extractValue(xml_input, concat(xpath,'/@title')),
      extractValue(xml_input, concat(xpath,'/@author')),
      extractValue(xml_input, concat(xpath,'/@unitprice')),
      extractValue(xml_input, concat(xpath,'/@quantity'))
    );
  END WHILE;

  -- all books are in the temporary table `books` ready for further processing
  SELECT * FROM books;
END;
;;
delimiter ;

CALL import_xml(@xml);
```

That being said, before jumping head down into parsing large XML into MySQL however, you may want to take a moment to contrast writing a long stored procedure with writing a sleek XSLT stylesheet that transforms an XML into a batch of SQL statements neatly wrapped into a transaction that you may readily load into MySQL. I'd say both approaches are worth your while.

Or perhaps: XML + XSLT that you run straight from MySQL?

HTH